# Set jQuery datepicker allowed times with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I need to set jQuery datepicker plugin allowed times by an ajax call

**This is my javascript:**

```
var al = function(currentDateTime) {   
    $.post("getdate.php", function(data) {
        $('#default_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            allowTimes: data
        });
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('#default_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        allowTimes: [
            '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00',
            '17:00'
        ],
        formatTime: 'H:i',
        formatDate: 'd.m.Y',
        defaultTime: '08:00',
        onChangeDateTime: al,
        timepickerScrollbar: true
    });
```

**And this is my php code in "getdate.php".**

```
<?php
    echo "'08:00', '09:00'";
?>
```

And I tried,

```
$times = array(
    '08:00', '09:00'
);

json_encode($times);
```

But both of them didn't work... (I'm using this plugin 'http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found the answer. We need to add these to ajax call parameters.

> dataType: "json", 
>   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

**So this is my js,**

```
var al = function(currentDateTime) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'getdate.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#default_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                    allowTimes: data
                });
            }
        });
    };

    $(function() {
        $('#default_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            allowTimes: [
                '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00',
                '17:00'
            ],
            formatTime: 'g:i A',
            formatDate: 'd.m.Y',
            defaultTime: '08:00',
            onChangeDateTime: al,
            timepickerScrollbar: true
        });

    });
```

**This is my php,**

```
<?php 
$times = array(
    '08:00', '09:00'
);
echo json_encode($times);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the property via an AJAX call you have to make sure that your call will be finished and successful before displaying your time picker. I think that this method can cause latency...

I thought of an other solution :

If you want to make the allowTimes property dynamic you can put your HTML/JS script into a .php file and make an echo of the allowed times you want after getting it in php.

```
<?php
//index.php
//
// Put here your script to get the allowed times. You can store them in a database, and make a simple SELECT request.
$allowed_times= "['08:00', '09:00']";

?>
<!-- your HTML CODE -->

<!-- your HTML CODE -->

$(function() {
        $('#default_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            allowTimes: <?php echo $allowed_times; ?>,
            formatTime: 'H:i',
            formatDate: 'd.m.Y',
            defaultTime: '08:00',
            onChangeDateTime: al,
            timepickerScrollbar: true
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need an ajax call